# How to auto-shrink text with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display 2 values on the same row and give the one on the right priority to grow (it is a mobile app and needs to detect the width of the screen and "squash" the left cell to be smaller.

Here is my attempt:  http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyjoyce/TxBhD/

HTML

```
<div id="screen">
    <div id="leftDesc">This is a Long Description</div>
    <div id="rightDesc">1000</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#screen
{    
    width: 200px;
}

#leftDesc
{    
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    max-width:160px;
    color: blue;
}

#rightDesc
{   
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
}
```

What should happen:  Increase "1000" to "1000 000". Blue text should chop off the end of the word "Description" and the red and blue text should stay on the same line.

Disclaimer: I am not very good at CSS - in XAML I use the * value on width so that a cell auto-grows and shrinks the others.

I do not want to use Javascript or JQuery.

Comment: Gah. The closest I can get to making this work includes a table with fixed layout, and jackweinbender's answer. Are you OK with `display:table;` answers?

Comment: Yes, that would usable, if it works ;)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if you can dynamically change the size of your floated elements with CSS based on the content, but *part* of the problem can be solved with:

Adding to `#leftDesc`:

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
white-space:nowrap;
```

The `white-space` property keeps the text on one line; `text-overflow` should be pretty self-explanatory.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jackweinbender/TxBhD/1/)

Comment: I don't think floated elements will get any smaller due to other floated elements. Your solution only solves half the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys - FWIW, they don't HAVE to be be floated, I just had to get the RightDesc to be right aligned and grow to the left

Answer (score 5):

Use the flexible box layout:

```
#screen
{    
    width: 200px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
}

#leftDesc
{    
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
    color: blue;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#rightDesc
{   
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
}
```

I've removed your `float`s and your `inline-block`s, and added `display: flex` to get the boxes to behave.

I've also added `white-space:nowrap;` to make sure the description gets cut off, like you've asked.

I've also removed `max-width:160px;`, because it didn't appear to have any effect in this scenario.

*Keep in mind that this will not work in IE.*

Comment: I can't wait until this has deeper support.

Comment: Thanks uber - however the Right text is not right aligned (Chrome) - see this updated JSF - the number grows to the right? - http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyjoyce/CpLjh/